# Bootstrap 3 and IE box model breaks my layout

Tags: zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap-3, css

I'm using Bootstrap 3 together with Zend Framework 1.12.3. Everything is working fine but when testing my site in Internet Explorer 7 the layout breaks because of the IE box model.

I'm now trying the [coliff / bootstrap-ie7](https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7) and [Schepp / box-sizing-polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill) but i can't get it to work. I've pasted the *behavior: url(/public/css/boxsizing.htc); after all box-sizing properties in the bootstrap.css file and i have placed the following code in my layout.phtml file:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link href="/css/bootstrap-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

I have also pasted "AddType text/x-component .htc" in my .htaccess file.

Does someone know why this is not working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the bootstrap-ie7.css is the path to the htc file. Make sure you've upload the .htc itself file to your css or js folder and put the path from the root in that .css.

```
 First line of the -ie7.css file {box-sizing:border-box;behavior:url(/js/boxsizing.htc)}
```

This path must be your relative root path. If the .htc is in the assets/js folder, put that in the behavior url parenthesis.

```
  {box-sizing:border-box;behavior:url(assets/js/boxsizing.htc)}
```

Comment: BTW, though the css works, the scripts may not work. I don't bother with ie 7 anymore.